# Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

This error keeps coming up when I execute gatsby develop.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        path
        title
        porcao
        tempo
        cover
      }
    }
  }
`
```

GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL queries.
  Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate defintitions for one or more documents: each document must have a unique name. Duplicated documents:
- cUsersUserDocumentsPwaPizzaSrcTemplatesRecipeTemplateJs2809623611

Answer (score 0):

> Encountered duplicate defintitions for one or more documents: *each document must have a unique name.*

This error is referring to your graphql query names (which seem to be non-unique).

Let's say you have an index page, and an about page, each with their own graphql query. If you name your queries, you must ensure that you give them unique names.

For example:

```
// src/pages/about.js

export const aboutPageQuery = graphql`
  query AboutQuery {...}
`
```

---

```
// src/pages/index.js

export const indexPageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {...}
`
```